# After a certain time, I want to turn off audio_service in the background with the android_alarm_manager plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, alarmmanager, backgroundworker, flutter-dependencies

After a certain time, I want to turn off [audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service) in the background with the [android_alarm_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager) plugin. How can I solve this problem?

When I try to do this, I get the following error.

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception:
>   MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method stop on
>   channel ryanheise.com/audioService)

My code is as follows.

**action.dart**

```
 FlatButton(
         onPressed: () async {
              await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(Duration(minutes: _minute.floor().toInt()), 0, backgroundCallback);
              Navigator.pop(context);
         },
         child: Text(S.of(context).set),
    )
```

**main.dart**

```
void backgroundCallback() async {
  AudioService.connect();
  AudioService.stop();
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  init();
  await sl<DotEnv>().load('.env');

  //get theme
  bool _isDarkTheme = await sl<SharedPreferenceHelper>().isDarkTheme() ?? false;

  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
  }

  runApp(MainApp());
}
```

**Flutter and Dart version:**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.720], locale tr-TR)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.9 at D:\flutter
    • Framework revision f139b11009 (11 days ago), 2020-03-30 13:57:30 -0700
    • Engine revision af51afceb8
    • Dart version 2.7.2
```

Comment: Could you try [flutter packages cache repair] first and try again?

Comment: I tried but the result is the same.

Comment: After registering the alaram callback are you closing the application?

Comment: @HemanthRaj Open or close gives the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, although you have to wait until it is actually connected using "await":

```dart
await AudioService.connect();
AudioService.stop();
```

For this to work, you will also need to upgrade to release 0.9.0 or later which mentions in the CHANGELOG:

- Allow connections from background contexts (e.g. android_alarm_manager).